# Embedded Navigation Bar not showing at runtime.

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have embedded a Navigation Controller within my UiTableViewController in hopes of having a Navigation bar. The navigation bar shows within the storyboard but at runtime it does not display. Has anyone else ran into this problem and can provide a solution? I have read into many Stackoverflow posts but can not find one regarding this problem that works.

[image: Storyboard]

[image: Storyboard Hiearchy]

[image: Runtime]

Comment: how you are calling/presenting the table view?

Comment: The tableview has been done through the storyboard so far. I have not done anything programmatically .

Comment: it is ok if done using storyboard. IS your tableview the only view in your storybaord ?

Comment: No there are other view controllers i am using they are experiencing the same problem.

Comment: There are 3 different views within a scrollview.

Comment: is your table view the first view that loads? Select nav controller and click on initial view controller on storyboard attribute inspector, and check if nav bar loads or not

Comment: thank you so much it worked. Thats all it was. @Mr.T

Comment: may be you missed the making the nav bar as initial view controller part from my answer :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must be presenting the plain table view instead of navigation controller. What you need to do is make you tableview as root view for a navigation controller and present the navigation controller.

```
 yourTableController *vc = //reference from storyboard
            UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
     //then present the nav instead of tableview.
```

**In Swift:**

```
  var nav: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
  //then present the nav
```

Or if you want your tableview as the initial view controller, then make your navigation controller(whose root view is your table view) as initial view controller in your storyboard.

Comment: This is in swift. Sorry i didn't say that but i will try what you mentioned. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the Navigation bar via [ Editor -->Embed in --> Navigation Controller ] then let's say you added a UIBarButtonItem name forward

you select that items button and drag it to another view controller, it pops up stating if you want to segue show etc... and you select segue show.

later date you decide to add another UIBarButtonItem say previous and you drag this button back to the main view controller.

upon the run time you now see a white empty space try the following fix

1st) ensure you have identified in both segue in the 'Storyboard segue' click on the circle to get to this area.

2nd) delete the segue not the Navigation Bar!

3rd) recreate the segue by dragging it to the controller

the problem should be fixed please do tick if this solution has helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false

if let _navigationItem = embeddedViewController?.navigationItem {
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.pushItem(_navigationItem, animated: false)
}
```